# Show that $\sum_{p\le n}(-1)^{(p+1)/2}\ge 0$ for all $n$?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $p$ is odd prime

Define function $f$,

$$f(n)=\sum_{p\le n} -1^{\frac{p+1}2}$$

> claim 1: The values of $f(n)$ never equal to negative integer or $f(n)\ge 0$ for all $n$

It is checked up to $3000$

Example: $n=5$ and $f(5)=(-1)^{(3+1)/2}+(-1)^{(5+1)/2}=1+(-1)=0$

Define function $F$,

$$F_k(n)=\sum_{p\le n}-1^{\frac{p+k}2}$$

> Claim 2:$$F_k(n) = \begin{cases} \ge 0 &\mbox{if } k \equiv 1 \\
> \le 0 & \mbox{if } k \equiv 3 \end{cases} \pmod{4}$$

Claim 2 is generalized form of Claim 1.

> > Can it be shown that above observation are true?

```
# Take input from user
upto = int(input("n : "))
while upto > 0:
    sum = 0
    
    for num in range(2, upto + 1):
    
        i = 2
        
        for i in range(2, num):
            if (int(num % i) == 0):
                i = num
                break;
    
        #If the number is prime then add it.
        if i is not num:
            sum += (-1)**((num+1)/2)
    
    print("\n f(", upto, "):", sum)
    upto = upto -1;
```

Comment: FYI, this is related to [Prime Number Races](https://dms.umontreal.ca/~andrew/PDF/PrimeRace.pdf).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It cannot be shown because it is not true. See [A38698](https://oeis.org/A038698), which lists these partial sums as a function of $n$ and says that the value becomes negative at the $2946$st prime for the first time.

Comment: thanks,Here $n$ should be 26861